# C++ Designing for SIMD: Making an SoA less of a PiTA

Tags: c++, optimization, architecture, simd

### Bittersweet SoAs

I've recently come to see the delights of using hand-written SIMD intrinsics with the SoA (structure of array) representation.

The speed improvements over my former AoS (array of structures) code, at least for straightforward sequential-type streaming operations, was little short of amazing with doubled to tripled speed ups. As a bonus, it simplified the logic to exclude those tricky horizontal operations and shuffling components around in addition to reducing memory use.

Yet then there's this bittersweet sense afterwards where I realize what a PITA they are to work with in code, especially interface design.

### Mid-Level Interface Design

I'm often dealing with designing mid-level interfaces. They're higher-level than say, `std::vector`, but lower-level than say, a `Monster` class in a video game. These are always some of the most awkward interfaces for me to design and keep stable, because they're not low-level enough to provide a simple read/write interface as with a standard C++ container. Yet they're not high-level enough (lacking sufficient logic in the entry points in the interface) to completely hide and abstract away the underlying representation and only provide high-level operations.

An example of what I consider a mid-level design is a programmable particle system API which desires to be as efficient and scalable as possible for certain scenarios while being convenient for casual scenarios (ex: to scripters). Such a design has to offer particle access, and unless it's going to have a method for every possible algorithm related to particles imaginable, it'll have to expose some of those raw SoA details somewhere, somewhere, to let clients benefit from them.

The design also shouldn't necessarily be made to require SoA type code to be written all the time. The more daily usage still does not demand utmost efficiency so much as convenience, simplicity, productivity. It's only for those rarer, performance-critical scenarios where the underlying SoA representation comes in handy.

So how do you API/lib designers and large-scale system guys deal with balancing these types of needs?

### Balancing Multiple Access Patterns

Since the SoA obliterates away any per-element structure, might it be a decent idea to instantiate structs/classes on the fly as the user accesses the `nth` element using the more convenient, random-access portions of the interface? Perhaps a structure containing pointers/references to the nth entries of multiple SoA arrays for mutable access?

Also if the more common usage patterns are more random-access scalar logic rather than sequential-access SIMD vector logic, but the SIMD portions are triggered enough to still make it better to just use one data structure for it all, might this kind of hybrid SoA representation balance all the needs better?

```
struct AoSoA
{
    ALIGN16 float x[4];
    ALIGN16 float y[4];
    ALIGN16 float z[4];
};
ALIGN16 AoSoA elements[n/4];
```

I don't understand the nature of cache lines that well to know if this kind of representation is worthwhile. I have noticed it doesn't help so much for the sequential SIMD cases where we can devote the full resources to one bulky algorithm, but it seems like it might be helpful for cases that need a lot of horizontal logic across components or random-access scalar logic cases where the system might be doing a lot of other things at the same time.

Anyway, I'm generally looking for insight into how to effectively design middle-level data structure interfaces with SoA backend representations as implementation details without transferring the complexity to the client unless they really want it.

I really want to avoid forcing clients to always write SoA-type code in every place that uses the interface unless they really need that efficiency, and I'm curious as to how to balance those more daily, random-access scalar usage scenarios vs. the rarer but not too uncommon scenarios that take advantage of the SoA representation.

Comment: Perhaps a strategy such as used by the standard library, where algorithm interfaces always take iterators rather than a reference to a container? The iterators hide the underlying structure and make it irrelevant.

Comment: @MarkRansom There I kind of recurse back to where the iterator needs to return something resembling a complete element (a complete particle, e.g.), but perhaps I could simply construct those on the fly by aggregating all the nth elements of those SoA arrays.

Comment: @MarkRansom One of the things I was tempted to do, and this deals more with backend implementation than interface, is to generalize like a `Container<T1, T2, T3, ...>` that stores those parallel aligned SoA arrays for each `Tn`, with a `value_type` defined to be a structure (tuple) with `N` members we can create on the fly containing the components of the nth element returned by its iterators and operator[]. I'm not sure if that's overkill, but it'd tuck away some of the awkwardness of dealing with SoAs to one generalized container to test and maintain.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but there was a really good talk by Insomniac at GDC this year about SIMD in their engine that you might find interesting: http://www.gdcvault.com/play/1022249/SIMD-at-Insomniac-Games-How

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually don't know enough software engineering to formulate a general strategy for what you want to do, but in particular for the AoS vs SoA problem, I found this paper by Robert Strzodka fascinating: http://asc.ziti.uni-heidelberg.de/sites/default/files/research/papers/public/St11ASX_CUDA.pdf

The goal of this abstraction is to provide an easy way to switch between AoS and SoA and even more complicated nestings. The author uses it to show how performance can change with different access patterns without touching the algorithmic part, and without the pain of recoding all of your accesses.

Although it is focused more on the GPU side, the code provided works on CPUs as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a decent fit so far with this kind of "hybrid SoA" or "AoSoA" rep internally.

```
struct HybridSoA
{
     ALIGN float x[4];
     ALIGN float y[4];
     ALIGN float z[4];
};
```

It balances those sequential fast paths using SIMD with random-access and slower paths that don't really care about SIMD with a design that preserves reasonable spatial locality for random-access paths.

For the interface, I haven't gotten too fancy yet, just returning pointers to these structures for those fast sequential paths and proxies allowing scalar-style access for `operator[]` and so forth.

The interface kind of leaks some of its internals for the SIMD path but it seems inevitable as the design can't anticipate all the high-level needs without growing increasingly monolithic, and it's abstracted in a way and with tight ABI concerns that makes it difficult to utilize a richer interface (the actual interface is coded in C with a C++ wrapper on top).

Perhaps it might be better though if I provided a `foreach` kind of method that accepted a function pointer (or something which ultimately translates into one like `std::function`, though I can't use it directly due to ABI reasons) that gets called back instead of directly exposing internal handles. It could be fed this SoA data required for SIMD in bulk to mitigate the calling overhead, and that'd alleviate a temporal coupling issue I have where write accesses to the structure require an explicit `commit` call to record the changes to the application history.

Iterators might be nice if they double over as ways to access the data in a proxy-style form (less raw exposure). Though I've kind of fallen out of love with iterators for all but generic containers and especially where the algorithms associated don't fall into a generalized category. I just found it a burden in the past to maintain iterators for everything (a burden that outweights the benefits of using a range-based for over `operator[]`, e.g.), and have come to favor a kind of bastardized aesthetic between C and C++ (just for these kinds of mid-level data structures which are more complex than a standard container and store disparate types of data, but aren't high-level enough to impose many constraints on the public interface beyond a generic container).

Just for these specific types of data structures, I've found it most productive to favor the interface aesthetic of a plain old C-style array, though that's definitely biased and certainly just a result of my own tendencies. For things like meshes, I just keep finding myself increasingly being drawn to a C-style aesthetic, if only because I kept erring on the side of too many layers of code in the past for these cases to a point where I became confused by my own creations.

Appreciate all the answers and comments so far!